# Python share variables between functions but not threads

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, share, global

I am writing some code that i have threaded, and am using various different functions at once. I have a variable called `ref` that is different for each thread.

`ref` is defined within a function within the threaded function, so when I use global `ref`, all the threads use the same value for `ref` (which I don't want). However when I don't use global `ref`, other functions can't use `ref` as it is not defined.

E.g.:

```
def threadedfunction():
    def getref():
        ref = [get some value of ref]
    getref()
    def useref():
        print(ref)
    useref()
threadedfunction()
```

Comment: Have you heard of arguments and return values? You should be using those to communicate data into and out of functions.

Comment: That's something you need to be 100% comfortable with before you even consider doing anything multithreaded.

Comment: If you're writing between threads, you also need to use threadsafe types. Python's builtin types aren't guaranteed to be safe.

Comment: I think you need to expand the code in your question because I can't understand your problem. But check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local

Comment: I can't see how to answer this question: how is the threading being managed (with stdlib or something else)?, where is this global ref, did you just remove your running-but-broken code and replace it with some theoretical thing that can't run at all? In your code, `ref` is scoped in `getref()`, and won't exist when you try to call `useref`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If defining `ref` as `global` doesn't fit your needs then you don't have many other options...

Edit your function's parameters and returns. Possible solution:

```
def threadedfunction():

    def getref():
        ref = "Hello, World!"
        return ref # Return the value of ref, so the rest of the world can know it

    def useref(ref):
        print(ref) # Print the parameter ref, whatever it is.

    ref = getref() # Put in variable ref whatever function getref() returns
    useref(ref) # Call function useref() with ref's value as parameter

threadedfunction()
```